# Event propagation in Nativescript

Tags: nativescript

In Nativescript core (6.5) - I've got a layout with a tap event and also a button inside it with tap event.

If I click on the button - the tap event for the layout gets called first and then the button event.

Is there any way to get just the button event.

If not, get the button event first.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the related xml?

Comment: `isPassThroughParentEnabled` should have helped here but there is an [open issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/6606). A workaround could be using a Label, design it like a button for this senario.

Comment: The problem with Label is I don't get the Button effect. should this attribute be disabled and should it be on the Button or the container?